# How to calculate mean absolute error horizontally(row-wise) on 2D numpy.array with sklearn.metrics?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I've tried to calculate mean_absolute error of all rows of an 2-D array. Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error as mae


arr = np.array([[1.7, 3.1], [2.1, 2.7], [0.9, 0.7], [0.3, 0.8]])
result_arr = np.apply_along_axis(mae, 0, arr[:, 0], arr[:,1])
```

However, I got result like that:

```
array(0.675)
```

I want to get mae values like this(row-wise):

```
array([[mae_value1],
       [mae_value2],
       [mae_value3],
       [mae_value4]])
```

By the way, I have to calculate mae with sklearn.metrics and without loop. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may be confused about the mean absolute error metrics. `mae` calculates mean error for two sets of items (predictions and y values of a test set), and this is why it returns one number.

Your desired result indicates that you are looking other some metrics on each row of your array, not the mean of all these rows. What do you want to see there? A difference between two numbers, a difference between absolute of these two numbers, etc.

If you really want to get `mae` you should understand that this metrics is used in `sklearn` in the context of machine learning. When you feed data to `sklearn.mae`, you should feed data from two sources: your predictions from your machine learning algorithm, and y values from your test set.

If machine learning is not your context, then you need to provide more information on what you are actually doing, in order for someone to help you.